# Select all fields after group in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in mongoDB, for example:

```
{
    "_id": "myId",
    "firstName": "myFirstName",
    "lastName": "myLastName",
    "email": "my@email.com",
    "age": 88,
    "city": "myCity",
    "country": "myCountry"
}
```

Then, I have `lookup`, `unwind` and `group` by _id in pipeline. Is there any way of not listings all fields, when I need all fields?

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "someItemsFromLookup": { "$push": "$someItemsFromLookup" }
        "firstName": { "$first": "$firstName" },
        "lastName": { "$first": "$lastName" },
        "email": { "$first": "$email" },
        "age": { "$first": "$age" },
        "city": { "$first": "$city" },
        "country": { "$first": "$country" }
    }
}
```

I need something like this, where `*` is "all fields":

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "someItemsFromLookup": { "$push": "$someItemsFromLookup" }
        "*": { "$first": "*" },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$$ROOT` with [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator and then use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with the first field to get it on the root place.

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "someItemsFromLookup": { "$push": "$someItemsFromLookup" },
  "first": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
}},
{ "$replaceRoot": {
  "newRoot": {
    "$mergeObjects": [
      "$first",
      { "someItemsFromLookup": "$someItemsFromLookup" }
    ]
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$first` with `$$ROOT`

```
{
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "someItemsFromLookup": { "$push": "$someItemsFromLookup" },
        "firstDocument": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
```